# why do switch in android layout does not work in my code?

Tags: android

I ve added a switch in my android xml, I also have a few Edit_text boxes, say a 9 in the same activity. My objective is to make them visible in a single click. And here goes my Java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//static int count = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Switch mySwitch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
    mySwitch.setChecked(true);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if(isChecked)
            {
                LinearLayout pop = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
                pop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            else
            {
                LinearLayout pop = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
                pop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });



}
```

And the problem is that, when I run this in device/emulator I am unable to change the state of the switch. Any help will be appreciated . :)

XML code :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:>


    <Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchButton"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:switchMinWidth="14.5sp"
    android:switchPadding="14.5sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout

   android:id="@+id/linear"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">



   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextOne"
       android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
       android:background="#1ec0e9"
       android:alpha="0.5"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextTwo"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:alpha="0.6"
       android:background="#cacaca"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextThree"
       android:background="#1ec0e9"
       android:alpha="0.5"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextFour"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:alpha="0.6"
       android:background="#cacaca"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextFive"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#1ec0e9"
       android:alpha="0.5"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextSix"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:alpha="0.6"
       android:background="#cacaca"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextSeven"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#1ec0e9"
       android:alpha="0.5"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextEight"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:alpha="0.6"
       android:background="#cacaca"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editTextNine"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#1ec0e9"
       android:alpha="0.5"
       android:ems="13"
       android:gravity="left"
       android:typeface="monospace"
       />



   </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml layout..

Comment: Why did you initialize the `pop` `LinearLayout` twice? You can initialize it just once in your `onCreate`.

Comment: I mean to say full layout, I wanna see is there only one Parent Layout or You are putting your child views ie edit text in another layout under Parent Layout.

Comment: @iRuth  , I did try that , but the Android studio warns me that "variable 'pop' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: Another thing is why is the `xmlns` tag property empty in your `RelativeLayout`? You should declare the `pop` variable in your class (just like you declared the `count` variable) and not in `onCreate`. That should fix the warning.

Comment: I use all those, but this site doesn;t allow me to use all those references properly, thats  why i omitted that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Option:

Just change your parent RelativeLayout with LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 


   Your remaining views

 </LinearLayout> // Ending Parent Linear Layout
```

Second Option:

If you don't wanna change your layout from Relative to Linear,just do this

Instead of setting margin_top=150dp to your editfield set it to your ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Your switch starts working

Comment: It worked, can you tell me why it did not work when it was relative ?

Comment: Actually your scroll view is actual culprit its overlapping your Switch that why you are not been able to trigger any event on switch